# Telnet connection to a remote machine and finding firefox version on it

Tags: java, browser, version, telnet

I established a telnet connection to a remote machine using the following program and now I wish to find the version of the firefox browser present on the remote computer. How do I do it?

Program for telnet connection:

```
package conn;
import org.springframework.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import org.apache.commons.net.telnet.TelnetClient;

public class BV1 extends HttpServlet
{
    private TelnetClient telnet = new TelnetClient();

    public BV1(String server, String user, String password )
    {
        try
        {
            telnet.connect(server, 3389);
            System.out.println("Connected to : "+server);


            telnet.getKeepAlive();
            System.out.println("Is telnet connected : "+telnet.isConnected());



            telnet.disconnect();
            System.out.println("Is telnet connected : "+telnet.isConnected());
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private String getCurrentWorkingDirectory() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try 
        {
             BV1 telnet = new BV1("remotehost_server","username","password");
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If your server has telnet enabled, you should disable it.

Comment: I did it. What do I do now?

Comment: Use a secure protocol and not telnet

Comment: Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work, ensure that one machine is in the TelnetClients group of the other.